# Java mysql read modify write

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way in Java using MySQL connector, I can perform a read modify write atomically, i.e., I want to perform this:

```
// pseudocode
atomic
{
   r = getRecord();
   r = processRecord(r);
   writeRecord(r);
}
```

I am a little hesitant to lock the entire table using mysql LOCK command because I can't reliably unlock the contentious table. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By atomically, I'm assuming you mean transactionally? If you set the autocommit state on your database connection to false, and commit after each `writeRecord(r)` then you'll only be locking record r.

If you want to ensure that r does not get changed between your `getRecord()` and `writeRecord(r)` methods by another process, then you couls apply a shared lock by [locking in SHARED MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Something along the lines of :

```
   // pseudocode
   connection = getConnection();
   connection.setautoCommit(false);
   r = getRecord(connection);
   r = processRecord(r);
   writeRecord(r,connection);
   connection.commit();
```

Comment: In my case, it is possible that due to some external reason that the process could die, then would the lock be set free? allowing others to access if the process fails in processRecord. 4 spaces after a new line gives code formatting :)

Comment: Thanks transactions is what I was looking for, appreciate it.

Comment: If the processes fails then, in an exception handler, you should look to issue a connection.rollback() - this will put the database back to the state it was in at the beginning of the transaction and release the locks.

Comment: It is not necessary to rollback when process dies. DBMS server will rollback when connection is closed.

Comment: Vlad, that was what I was hoping should happen, thank you for confirming. Dave, in my case the process could die like a power outage for example, while other hosts can access the record. So the exception handler may not run. Thank you both.